# How to delete Cloud Firestore data automatically based on timers?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data under certain collections that I want to have deleted automatically based on how long the user chooses the data to be inputted in the database for.

Is there a specific google firebase mechanism / method that I can apply, etc.

How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [firebase cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) with `httpTrigger`, but you will need to use a separate service to trigger it with cron jobs running.

If you are giving the user choice on a certain amounts they can chose, you can run cron jobs at all those intervals and handle which items to be deleted on trigger. If user's choice is arbitrary then you will probably want to run cron jobs at a certain smaller interval and handle which data to be deleted in the trigger function.

For cron jobs you can use something like [cron-jobs.org](https://cron-job.org/en/) that would trigger your function at certain time intervals. Or you can deploy your own service like https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron/ .